# Controlling Motor Speed with MCP4162-104E Digital Potentiometer

Tags: raspberry-pi, breadboard, debugging, digital-potentiometer

I am new to electronics and this is my first time using a digital potentiometer. My goal is to control the speed of a DC motor using the [MCP4162-104E](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/268/MCHPS02713_1-2520653.pdf) digital potentiometer. I am confident in the wiring that the wiring is correct, however I am running into issues writing the code that will change the digital potentiometers resistance. I am looking to have a loop that will continuously change the potentiometers resistance that way I will see the motors speed increase when the resistance is low and decrease when the resistance is high.

[image: MCP4162 Digital Potentiometer Pinout]

The figure above is the pinout for the MCP4162 and currently I have the following connections:

1. CS is currently connected to SPI0 CE0 on the RPI.
2. SCK is connected to the RPI SCLK (GPIO11).
3. SDI is connected to MOSI (GPIO10).
4. Vss is connected to ground.
5. P0W is connected to the positive terminal of the motor.
6. P0B is connected to ground.
7. SDO is connected to MISO (GPIO9).
8. Vdd is connected to +3.3 V.

The connections above can be seen in the breadboard level schematic I made below.

[image: Breadboard Schematic]

Lastly, I below this is the code that I have so far. Please let me know if there are any errors/mistakes. Thank you in advance.

[image: Code Segment]

From what I understand from the data sheet, I believe where my issue is where I am writing to the MCP4162. Based on the data sheet I must send an 8-bit command byte followed by another data byte, which can be seen below. However, I am not sure how to do this within my code.

[image: Command and Data Byte Structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are connecting the digital pot in series with the motor, so all motor current will flow through the pot.

The datasheet states that the Absolute Maximum current on the pot leads is 2.5 mA.  Unless you have an extremely small motor, this will not be anywhere near enough current to drive the motor.

Comment: I also attempted this with an LED and still ran into some issues.

Comment: Peter, you're right about this puny pot controlling too much motor current, but the OP's question involves interface to the RPI.

Comment: I am just looking for a way to see if the digital potentiometer values are actually being changed as I write to the digital potentiometer with my script. The DC motor can be replaced with something that consumes less current such as an LED I suppose.

Comment: A LED is highly non- linear and will give you strange results like only beginning to turn on at a third of the range. Use a fixed resistor to make a voltage divider and use a multimeter to measure the voltage.

Comment: @Kartman So I would connect the wiper of the digital pot to one leg of a resistor then measure the voltage across that?

Comment: You could simply use an ohmmeter to measure the resistance between the wiper and one end of the digital pot (measure between P0B and P0W).